# PHP require fails with no error

Tags: php, include, require

Here is the code I have been struggling for several hours:

```
if ((require $_SESSION['ROOT_PATH'] . '/templates/core/menu_js.php') == 'OK') {
   echo 'OK';
} else {
   echo 'KO';
}
```

If I understand the PHP documentation on the "require" directive correctly, the "KO" should never be written because, if the require doesn't work, an error is raised.

In my case, the "KO" is always displayed even with error tunning :

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_COMPILE_ERROR);
```

Note that the same require (or include) works perfectly in other pages of the site.

**EDIT**

The if structure has been added after watching the documentation.
At first, I had a single line :

```
require $_SESSION['ROOT_PATH'] . '/templates/core/menu_js.php';
```

As I checked that this line was not working, I added the `if`.

By the way. Required page (when it works) adds a `script` tag to calling page that I never see on this unique page. On any other page where this require is used, the script appears on output.

So my question should be "if the output of the required php file is not displayed, why is there no error raised ?"

Comment: Does menu_js.php actually have a statement that says: return 'OK'? If not, it will always say 'KO'. See also: http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 4):

According to [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

> Successful includes, unless overridden by the included file, return 1... Also, it's possible to return values from included files. You can take the value of the include call as you would for a normal function.

So your file isn't returning 'OK'. It's returning either 1 (for success) or a custom value.

`require` is a language construct, not a standard function.  By using `require` you're already indicating the code should fail if the file isn't found.  Most likely you do not need to check the return value.

Comment: You're right. That's why I can't understand why the "KO" is displayed.

Answer (score 3):

This only works the way you expect if `menu_js.php` contains `return 'OK';`. Otherwise the `require` works just fine, but the returned value is not "OK", which is why your "KO" condition is triggered. `require` doesn't return `'OK'`. If the `require` does not work, the program is halted immediately, your `false` condition will never be hit the way you think it will.

Answer (score 2):

There are some mistakes here:

1. According to the PHP documentation:

   > `require` is identical to `include` except upon failure it will also produce a fatal `E_COMPILE_ERROR` level error.

   A fatal error will stop your script execution.
2. `require` returns what the included file returns:

   ```
   // a.php
   return 'test';

   // b.php
   $result = require 'a.php';
   echo $result; // will display 'test'
   ```

So, don't test the return value of `require`! Use `is_file()`, then if `true`, require that file!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `require` in `if`

Use this

```
if(file_exists($_SESSION['ROOT_PATH'] . '/templates/core/menu_js.php'))
{
 echo 'OK';
} else {
   echo 'KO';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but, as I said in the question, the EXACTLY SAME line (eg the "require" one) works in many other pages of my site so i KNOW for sure that the file exist.

Comment: @jhonraymos: From the PHP include manual: Successful includes, unless overridden by the included file, return 1. It is possible to execute a return statement inside an included file in order to terminate processing in that file and return to the script which called it.

Comment: Your first sentence is my answer :
    You cannot use require in if
But where is it written in documentation ?

Answer (score 1):

While it's true that the require will **not** return anything, making the conditional **always** return 'KO' since the left hand value in the parenthesis will never equal 'OK', you can check to see if the file has failed by setting the display_errors ini value in this script temporarily On.

Since you have your error reporting set to catch this, your display_errors is probably off, therefore not showing you this. Set it for this script like this:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```